# How to compile .cl file that contains inline assembly for GCN cards?

Tags: opencl, amd-gpu, amd-rocm, amd-gcn

There are some examples of inline assembly inside .cl files:

- [Example #1](https://community.amd.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FROCm-Developer-Tools%2FLLVM-AMDGPU-Assembler-Extra%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fexamples%2Fgfx8%2Fs_memrealtime_inline.cl)
- [Example #2](https://community.amd.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fzawawawa%2Fgatelessgate%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2FCore%2Fbinary-kernel%2Fequihash.cl)

But I cannot find the way they can be compiled.

ROCM has [this guide](https://community.amd.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Frocm.github.io%2FQuickStartOCL.html).

It seems that you can just export the env that points to ROCm's OpenCL and build your project as usual.

I wonder if that can automatically handle inline ASM.

I use AMDGPU pro driver.

Can I compile with a ROCm compiler and run it with an AMDGPU pro driver?

Also, if I can transform OpenCL with inline ASM into an ISA file and then compile ISA with a pure ASM compiler, it will also work for me.

Comment: My guess is that you'd compile them just like any other OpenCL kernel, using clCreateProgramWithSource and clBuildProgram. They seem to use a language extension that only their compiler will take (in other words, these kernels won't work on Intel or NVIDIA GPUs, and not even older AMD GPUs).

Answer (score 1):

You need the ROCm Runtime (driver) to compile and run it.
AMDGPU Pro is not supporting assembly.

Comment: After some experimenting, it seems that it's difficult to find a good opencl driver that can compile kernel with inline assembly on the fly. You need to use offline compilers. One option is to use llvm. But when I run it I found that functions like amd_bitallign or amdfe are not supported by llvm clang. Any suggestions?

Comment: I already written above. Install ROCm driver. llvm is used by ROCm.

Comment: I need to run it on amdgpu pro dirver. I am trying to use official llvm clang to compile my kernel, not the one with rocm. No result yet.

Comment: I understand u. I had same problem and found no solution. unless hacking binary... https://openwall.info/wiki/john/development/AMD-IL